# quicksort, helper class problems, timesort, vector, c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, quicksort, helper

my biggest problem is getting the quickSortHelper class to work. i know what i want the parameters to be, and the stuff inside i need to call on is what i can't figure out. i've tried a mixture of using the partition and quicksort but i can't figure it out. the code is written like this because i will be using a timesort class in the future to solve and time 6+ sorting algorithms. i got it to work by just throwing the code inside main. but all i want inside main is what i have here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <random> 

//i know not all the above libraries are being used, once quickSort is 
//working i plan on adding it to 5 other sorting algorithms, where these
//are neccessary.

using namespace std;

void quickSort(vector<int>&, int, int);
int partition(vector<int>&, int, int);
double timeSort(vector<int> &v, function<void(vector<int>&)>f);

int main()
{
    vector<int>intVec(1000);
    generate(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), rand);

    int p = 0;
    int q = 1000;
    quickSort(intVec, p, q);

    auto time = timeSort(intVec, quickSort);
    for (auto i = 0u; i != intVec.size(); ++i)
    cout << intVec[i] << " ";
    cout << "\nQuick sort took " << time << " nanoseconds\n";

    char chubby;
    cin >> chubby;
    return 0;
}
double timeSort(vector<int> &v, function<void(vector<int>&)>f)
{
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f(v);
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return static_cast<double>(((end - start).count()));
}
int partition(vector<int>&intVec, int p, int q)
{
    int x = intVec[p];
    int i = p;
    int j;

for (j = p + 1; j < q; j++)
{
    if (intVec[j] <= x)
    {
        i = i + 1;
        swap(intVec[i], intVec[j]);
    }
}

    swap(intVec[i], intVec[p]);
    return i;
}

void quickSort(vector<int>&intVec, int p, int q)
{
    int r;
    if (p < q)
    {
        r = partition(intVec, p, q);
        quickSort(intVec, p, r);
        quickSort(intVec, r + 1, q);
    }
}
void quickSortHelper(vector<int>&intVec)
{
    //i want to make a call to the timeSort function with
    //quickSortHelper, i can't use quickSort directly because timeSort
    //only has 2 parameters, the vector to be solved, and the method of
    //solving it. i know 

}
```

Comment: What code is calling `quickSortHelper`? What is the purpose of `quickSortHelper`; what is the function supposed to do?

Comment: I'm having problems with my debugger.  Can you help me by running a debugger on your code and indicating the statement that has the issue?

Comment: Do you *need* to put the `timeSort` function into a class?

Comment: IHMO, you should get rid of the timeSort function and place the code directly into your `main` function.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ how to benchmark".

Comment: timeSort is suppose to call quickSortHelper to solve the vector and to time the amount of nanoseconds it took to solved the random integers. quick sort helper is what i want to be called in place of quickSort. i want this because quickSort has too many parameters for timeSort as is. i have 5 other sorting algorithms that are all using timeSort to clock the amount of time it took for them to be solved. i have that all working and i'm just trying to add this one in but i wanted to get it working by itself. the quick sort solves just great. my main concern is getting quickSortHelper to work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simplifying your program:

```
int main(void) 
{
    vector<int>intVec(1000);
    unsigned int duration = 0;
    for (unsigned int iteration = 0;
         iteration < 1000000;
         ++iteration)
    {
        generate(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), rand);

        int p = 0;
        int q = 1000;
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        quickSort(intVec, p, q);
        auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration += (end - start);
    }
    cout << "Average time for quicksort: " << (duration / 1000000) << "\n";
    cout.flush();

    return 0;
}
```

I made the following changes:
1) Running the sort for many iterations to get an average duration.
2) Removed the timing function; it only complicates things.

Comment: the timing function is what i'm using for the other 5 sorting algorithms. TimeSort solves the vector and times it, that is what i would prefer. this is interesting though. if i were to use this would i have to make another for loop iteration for each of the other 5 sorting algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

Umm... If I understand correctly, this should do it:

```
void quickSortHelper(vector<int>&intVec)
{
    quickSort(intVec, 0, intVec.size());
}
```